# Unable to set bg color on a button

Tags: python, tkinter, button, colors

I am trying to change the bg color of a tkinter button to red.  This is the method.

```
    def show_mine(self):
        print("mine")
        self.cell_btn_object.configure(bg='red')
```

"mine" is being printed to the terminal, so the method is being called.  But the button stays white.  If it makes a difference, I am using a Mac.

I went back to the button creation and tried to change to color to red.  Here is the relevant parts of the Cell object code.  (The original code did not have bg='red')

```
class Cell:

    all = []

    def __init__(self, x, y, is_mine=False):
        self.is_mine = is_mine
        self.cell_btn_object = None
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

        Cell.all.append(self)

    def create_btn_object(self, location):
        btn = Button(location, width=6, height=4, text=f"{self.x},{self.y}", bg='red')
        btn.bind("<Button-1>", self.left_click_actions)
        btn.bind("<Button-2>", self.right_click_actions)
        self.cell_btn_object = btn
```

Here is the relevant code in main

```
for x in range(settings.GRID_SIZE):
    for y in range(settings.GRID_SIZE):
        c = Cell(x, y)
        c.create_btn_object(center_frame)
        c.cell_btn_object.grid(column=x, row=y)
```

But the buttons stay white.  So it seems I cannot change the button color to red or even set the color to red at the start.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you running on a Macintosh? The Mac doesn't allow you to change the background color of buttons.

Comment: ok, thanks, I guess.  Yes I am running on a Mac.  Is there any work around?

Comment: search this site: this and similar questions have been answered several times.

Comment: My initial searches pointed out incorrect uses of Button.config().  I am now finding a few messages concerning this subject, but also finding many talking about lack of good documentation for Tkinter.  Also many tutorials or guides do not mention this.  Anyway, thanks for the info that Mac does not have button bg colors.

Comment: Here is link: https://pypi.org/project/tkmacosx/